# React JS detect active component and update navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React, so apologies if this is obvious.

I have several components on a single-page website. This is my App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Nav />
      <About />
      <Experience />
      <Portfolio />
      <Activities />
      <Contact />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the Nav component:

```
const Nav = () => {
    const [activeNav, setActiveNav] = useState('#');
    return (
        <nav>
            <a href='#' onClick={() => setActiveNav('#')} className={activeNav === '#'? 'active': ''}><BiHome/></a>
            <a href='#about' onClick={() => setActiveNav('#about')} className={activeNav === '#about'? 'active': ''}><AiOutlineUser/></a>
            <a href='#experience' onClick={() => setActiveNav('#experience')} className={activeNav === '#experience'? 'active': ''}><MdWorkOutline/></a>
            <a href='#portfolio' onClick={() => setActiveNav('#portfolio')} className={activeNav === '#portfolio'? 'active': ''}><AiOutlineCode/></a>
            <a href='#contact' onClick={() => setActiveNav('#contact')} className={activeNav === '#contact'? 'active': ''}><BiMessageSquareDetail/></a>
            </nav>
    )
}
```

As you can see, it has links to the other components. I have styled it as a floating navbar. When the user clicks on a link, they're taken to that section of the page. The link's class is changed to "active" - its CSS gets changed to distinguish it from the rest.

Now I want to do it the other way around. When a user scrolls to a component, say Experience, I want the class of the corresponding link in Nav to be changed to active. How can I do that?

Thanks very much for reading until the end :)

Comment: It might be easier to include an ID in the attributes for the containing element with the component name for each component. That way the anchor tags work naturally without registering the onClick handler.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use onScroll event to calculate the difference between component's height and page's scrollTop in real time

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did find a similar solution on SO but they had hard-coded heights. @Nova helped me out in getting component heights dynamically.